# Spring is here!

Tags: visual

Does springtime get you all wound up?

If so, feel free to consult what resembles
[the Staff of Asclepius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rod_of_Asclepius)
below.

**What panacean prescription therein could help you uncompress this spring?**

Only `O`s and `o`s carry the message.
 
`'`s and `.`s are present for
[anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing)
and should be regarded as  spaces.

```
                         .......OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO...
               ...OOOOOOOOOOOOOO'''''''ooo                       '''''''OOOOOO
         ..OOOOOOO'''''                ooo
      .OOOO'''                         ooo
   .OOO''                              ooo
  OO'                                  ooo
  OO.                                  ooo
   'Ooo..                            ..oooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO...
      'oooooo....         ...OOOOOOOOOOooo'''''''''''               ''''OOOOOO.
          '''oooooOOOOOOOOOOO'''''     ooo                                    OO
              ..ooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOO.....ooo                        .....OOOOOOO'
         ..OOOOO''''         '''''OOOOOoooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO'''
      .oOOO''                          ooo  '''''''''''''''''''
   .Ooo'                               ooo
  OO'                                  ooo
  OO.                                  ooo
   'Ooo..                            ..oooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO...
      'oOOOOO....         ...OOOOOOOOOOooo'''''''''''               ''''OOOOOO.
          '''OOOOoooOOOOOOOOO'''''     ooo                                    OO
              ..ooooOOOOOooooooooo.....ooo                        .....OoooOOO'
         ..OOOOO''''         '''''OOOOOoooOOOOOoooooooooOOOOOoooOOOOOOO'''
      .oOOO''                          ooo  '''''''''''''''''''
   .Ooo'                               ooo
  OO'                                  ooo
  OO.                                  ooo
   'Ooo..                            ..oooOOOOOOOOOOOOooooOOOOooooOOOOoo...
      'oooooo....         ...OOOooooOOOooo'''''''''''               ''''ooOOOO.
          '''oooooOOOOOooooOO'''''     ooo                                    OO
              ..OOOOOOOoooOOOOOOOo.....ooo                        .....oOOOOOO'
         ..ooOOO''''         '''''ooOOOoooOOOOOOOOOOOOOoooOOOOOOooooooo'''
      .oOoo''                          ooo  '''''''''''''''''''
   .Ooo'                               ooo
  OO'                                  ooo
  OO.                                  ooo
   'Ooo..                            ..oooOOOOOoooooooooooOOOOOOOOooooOO...
      'oOOOoo....         ...oooooooOOOooo'''''''''''               ''''OOOOOO.
          '''ooOOOOOOOOoooooo'''''     ooo                                    OO
              ..oOOOOOOoooOOOOOOOO.....ooo                        .....oOOOOOO'
         ..OOooo''''         '''''OOOOOoooOOOoooOOOOOOOoooOOOOOOooooooo'''
      .oOOO''                          ooo  '''''''''''''''''''
   .Ooo'                               ooo
  OO'                                  ooo
  OO.                                  ooo
   'Ooo..                         .....oooOOOoooOOOOOOOoooOOOOooooOOOOoo...
      'oOOOOO....      ....OOOOOOOOOOOOooo'''''''''''               ''''ooOOOO.
          '''OOooooOOOOoooo'''''       ooo                                    OO
            ..OOOooooOOOOooooooooO.....ooo                        .....OoooOOO'
       ..OOOOO'''''          '''''OOOOOOoooOOOOoooooooooooOOOoooOOOOOOO'''
    .oooO''                                 '''''''''''''''''''
  OOO'
```

Hint:

> The near-centered `ooo` column is a clue
>  that is slightly inconsistent with the overall solution.

Comment: OOoooOOoooOoooooOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO... I feel like I'm in a haunted house!

Comment: The irony of the title is it is currently raining here

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil First day of spring yesterday was 50F/10C... Today is 15F/-9.4C.... so much for spring here

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was simpler than I thought! All you had to do was

> compress the spring *more* - press each column down into 11 squares - and you get the instruction to
>  [image: relax]

Comment: That's a prescription I can get behind

Answer (score 1):

<sup>(Community evidence locker— feel free to add or correct)</sup>

Inner “coils” of the “spring”
have identical outlines,
so the shape may be summarized with increased contrast
by  representing places that are always capital `O` by `@`
and representing places that are sometimes `O` and sometimes `o`  by `+`.

```
                                @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
                  @@@@@@@@@@@@@@       ooo                              @@@@@@
           @@@@@@@                     ooo
       @@@@                            ooo
    @@@                                ooo
  @@                                   ooo
  @@                                   ooo
    @oo                                ooo@@@@@+++++++++++@@@@++++++++++
       o+++++                +++++++@@@ooo                              ++@@@@
             +++++++@@@++++++          ooo                                    @@
                ++++@@@+++++++++++     ooo                             ++++@@@
           +++++                  ++@@@ooo@@@+++++++++++++@@@++++++++++
       o@++                            ooo
    @oo                                ooo
  @@                                   ooo
  @@                                   ooo
    @oo                                ooo@@@ooo@@@@@@@ooo@@@@oooo@@@@oo
       o@@@@@              @@@@@@@@@@@@ooo                              oo@@@@
             @@oooo@@@@oooo            ooo                                    @@
              @@@oooo@@@@oooooooo@     ooo                             @ooo@@@
         @@@@@                    @@@@@@ooo@@@@ooooooooooo@@@ooo@@@@@@@
     ooo@
  @@@
```